# Is it possible to wrap and hide GLM, without a performance hit?

Tags: c++, glm-math

Being so portable it's unlikely I'd actually need to put GLM behind a wrapper, but for the sake of learning I wanted to see if I could anyway.

I had initially liked this quick trick:

```
// MyMaths.h
#define GLM_FORCE_CXX03
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

namespace mathspace
{ 
    using Matrix4 = glm::mat4; 
}
```

This allows as an example being able to call `mathspace::Matrix4` instead of `glm::mat4`. But then I realised this doesn't hide GLM from external files.

So instead I looked at the standard approach of putting everything that's GLM in a source file while keeping the header free of GLM code. That means having functions in the source file convert everything. (I considered pImpl but couldn't see a need for it.) So setting a couple of the basics (rotate and [][] operations), a header looked like this:

```
// MyMaths.h
#include "Direction3.h" // My own vec3 of some sort

namespace mathspace
{
    void Rotate(Matrix4& matrix, float angle, const Direction3& axis);

    class Matrix4
    {
    private:
        float** m_matrix;

    public:
        Matrix4();

        // All this Proxy stuff is to implement a [][] operator.
        class Proxy 
        {
        private:
            float* m_column;

        public:
            Proxy(float* column);

            float& operator[](int index)
            {
                return m_column[index];
            }
        };

        Proxy operator[](int index)
        {
            return Proxy(m_matrix[index]);
        }
    };
}
```

The obvious change with this approach is that I have to add each piece of functionality I want to the wrapper; in this case, the two overloads and Rotate() function.

But the real problem (I think) is performance. When it comes to the source file, this new Rotate() function is going to have to:

1. Convert/copy my float** matrix into a GLM matrix, AND the Direction3 to vec3
2. Call glm::rotate() with the GLM matrix
3. Convert the result back to my float** matrix

.. which doesn't seem good at all.

So, just re-iterating that this isn't about GLM but rather that GLM creates an example of what I'm trying to learn, the question is:

**Is it possible to wrap and hide GLM without a performance hit? And if so, how?**